# How to use cookies with Python requests module?

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests, request

I am trying to do a get request and saving the cookies from that and using it for a post request.
I tried that with this code:

```
s = requests.Session()
resp = s.get(url1)
resp2 = requests.post(url2, data=payload, headers=headers, cookies=s.cookies)
```

but I can't get this to work correctly. The post request won't have the same cookies as the get request.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already using `Session()`, its whole purpose is to save you the hassle of handling cookies. It already stores the cookies obtained from the server and automatically sends/updates them in subsequent requests.

Here's how you should do it:

```py
s = requests.Session()
resp = s.get(url1)
resp2 = s.post(url2, data=payload, headers=headers)
```